# Comparing Regularization Terms in Regression Models

Tags: regression

When learning about Regularization in Regression, I am used to seeing this in the following form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)):

[image]

When watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nYiGXooG4I), I see a similar equation as provided above:

[image]

The thing which I don't understand is that when comparing the second equation to the first equation - **why is there an integral in the second equation and why is there a second derivative of the function?**

Thanks!

Comment: $R(f)$ is a general penalty, and $R(f) = \int f''(x)^2dx$ is a specific penalty. $R(f)$ could be something else, like $R(f) = \int f'(x)dx$, $R(f) = \sup_{x}|f(x)|$, or $R(f) = ||f||_{\mathrm{RKHS}}$, where $||.||_{\mathrm{RKHS}}$ measures how quickly $f$ is oscillating.

Answer (score 1):

This video talks about fitting smoothing splines, so they want the splines in $f$ to be smooth. Since $f^{\prime\prime}$ is measuring the curvature of $f$, $\int (f^{\prime\prime}(x))^2dx$ is (proportional to) the average squared curvature.

So, this optimization penalizes large average curvature; apparently, smooth here means to be rather flat.